# Duplicating multiple shapefiles in multiple locations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, features, copy

I have created a design for a well pad with two well heads and an access road that I would like to duplicate in multiple (20) locations (i.e., the same site design will be used at multiple sites.) Because the design involves points (well heads), lines (roads) and polygons (well pads), where the spatial arrangement is important, I have multiple feature classes and I don't want to simply copy one, drag to a new location, then copy another and try to fit it back where it should go. Instead, I would like to copy the entire design, consisting of three feature classes--one of points, one of lines, and one of polygons--and paste it in a new location. Provided I am able to drag all of the elements together, I can use aerial imagery to line up the features where they should go on each site.

I'm indifferent as to whether I have multiple copies of each feature in the same feature class (i.e., 20 copies of the well pad) or multiple feature classes (i.e., 20 feature classes with one well pad).

Any suggestions?

Using ArcGIS 10.3, Desktop, Basic license, with Spatial Analyst Extension.

Comment: From a data management point of view, you really want to end up with 1 feature class with multiple well pads, etc.
You might almost be on the right track.  Instead of copying the well pad, roads and well heads and moving individually, copy and paste each set.  That will create new copies of each one on top of the prior.  Then, select each of the new features you want to move, and move them as a group.  As long as they are located in the same location, they will all be editable at the same time, so you can move them all.  This would require them being in a common feature dataset.

Comment: I (still) don't think Arcmap does this out-of-the-box.  ArcFM has been able to do this for some time now with Composite Favorites.  If you're willing to write code, it's not that hard.  http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.1/DesktopUsing/CompositeFavorites.html

Comment: If you copy your features (exactly) to another location (workspace) with explorer, ArcCatalog or RoboCopy, add the copy to a map and start editing and use the spatial adjustment toolbar with affine you can move (by adding displacement links, also rotate and scale) the copy to a new location (yes, all the points, lines and polygons at the same time - everything that's currently editable!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Point, Line and Polygon template features are in a single File Geodatatbase, you can copy/paste the fgdb in ArcCatalog or File Explorer creating a new Well Pad. To move the new well pad features to the correct location, select all features in the 3 feature classes, they will move at the same time. You can also Scale, Rotate, etc multiple features in multiple feature classes at the same time.